# Spring Profiling

Tags: java, spring, spring-profiles

I have 2 URLs among which 1 is specific to Dev and the other to Prod.
I am also using Spring profiling where i have seperate file for dev and prod application-dev.properties and application-prod.properties and my 
appication.properties file look like this for Dev env

spring.profiles.active=dev

Now in my java code i want to have one property which will bind to the appropriate value depending on the spring profile i am using. How can i do it.

**Current Java Class:-**

```
//DEV
    private static final String WIND_RESOURCE_EXTRACTOR_URL = "https://localhost:9090/dev";

    //FOR PROD
    //private static final String WIND_RESOURCE_EXTRACTOR_URL = "https://localhost:9090/prod";
```

SO i want to mention this properties in my application-dev.properties or application-prod.properties file and my java class should pick the correct value based on the current spring profile.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to inject the value from your properties file. Assuming all the setup has already been done to read from the properties to the enviroment, i assume it has been.

```
    public class MyClazz {
         private final String myUrl;
         @Autowired
         public MyClazz(@Value("${my.url.property.name}") String myUrl){
           this.myUrl = myUrl;
   }
```

and within your two properties files place a `my.url.property.name=WhateverValueIwant`.